# how to add form field or model field which support all types characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-model-field

I have a `UserInfo` model which contains various fields. In the `username_in_bangla` field I want the user to give his/her name in Bangla text.

**models.py**

```py
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    facebook_id = models.URLField(blank=True)
    username_in_bangla = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="গনি")
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```py
class UserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
    model = UserInfo
    fields = (
        'username_in_bangla',
        'facebook_id',
        'profile_pic'
    )
```

I want a username that supports all types of characters including Bangla.
But when I give bangla text it shows **This value may contain only letters, numbers, and @/./+/-/_ characters.**
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where is this error occurring?

Comment: beside username input field

Comment: Is your error for the `username` field in the user model or for your `username_in_bangla` field? A `CharField` normally doesn't use the `UnicodeUsernameValidator` (The validator which is probably causing your error).

Comment: username field in the user model

Comment: What's the problem then? Don't you want to use the `username_in_bangla` field for that purpose? You wouldn't get the error for that. Or if the case is you want to use the username field itself then why even mention a `username_in_bangla` field in your question? It will just distract / confuse people about your question.

Comment: Sorry for that.